# Run getElementById outside arrow function for languages.js

Tags: javascript

I am making multilingual website using languages.js.org, according to its documentation, you run js code like this:

```
Languages.init(['en', 'fr'], './resources/', () => {
document.getElementById('str').innerHTML = 'hello'.t()
  });
```

But since I have a large lines of translation, I don't want to run getElementById in that Languages function because of performance issue, instead I want to run it outside that function:

```
Languages.init(['en', 'fr'], './resources/', () => {
      });
document.getElementById('str').innerHTML = 'hello'.t()
```

And it doesn't work, so how can I run getElementById outside that arrow function? Just for better performance on large file of translation

Comment: How exactly are you looking to get better performance by moving it outside of that function? Looks to me like that's a callback meant to be fired after the languages are initialized, I don't think that `.t()` method will exist before then.

Comment: getElementById is _about as fast as you can optimize code to be_, certainly as performant as simply doing an object access: it doesn't go through the DOM "looking for your element", it simply tries to access the element associated with that `id` in the id lookup table and immediately gives you an answer. Either it's there, or it's not. So as George asked: how do you know _that code_ is a performance issue?

Comment: I am using with ajax, and in my ajax runs a lot of other js, and I afraid let Languages initiate too many lines of translation will cause performance issue

Comment: of course it will, but that has nothing to do with `document.getElementById`. The general approach to serving heavily translated content is "create language-specific bundles offline, and serve the right one based on which locale the browser says it is", with language specific URLs (blah.com/en-US/, blah.com/zn-CN, etc) that load one specific bundle. You can make that a little more dynamic by having the server apply the translations when a page is requested and then caching it, but it's effectively the same thing.

Comment: ok, thanks for the idea